# Sharepoint 2010 webparts

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I need to have a web part on my site that gives me 5 days weather forecast and to be able to customize it anyone would have an interesting one that I would be able to manipulate it's CSS to have a custom design.and I need it's source code to add it to my project

Comment: Are you looking for a third-party web part?

Comment: yes I'm looking for these types of web part.

Comment: from where you will get the data to display in your webpart??is it external datasource??or you will save in the sharepoint list every day??

Comment: I'll have to get my data from an external datasource

Comment: Does the external datasource provide a web part? Or have you not found one yet? What are the parameters of the weather forcast ( local, national, global? What country? )

Comment: The country is Qatar I haven't found one yet have you got in interesting one with it's source code

Comment: No I don't have one, but am interested in what others have to say. I would suggest looking at Google or the BBC Met office to see whether either of them can provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/7649 - this is a codeplex one, so you should be able to take the code and make it however you want.